# Class Not Found Exception when I try to run the program

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception

I used `mvn install` to download all the dependencies for a java bundle. Then I wrote the test program and compiled it. It compiled without errors. But when I try to run it, it throws a run time exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:8)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Here is the target directory:

[image]

I have placed my `Tester` class immediately inside `classes` directory. I have verified that `com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module` exists in the lib directory.

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

Here is the `pom.xml` that came with the java bundle:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-java-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>swagger-java-client</name>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<prerequisites>
  <maven>2.2.0</maven>
</prerequisites>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12</version>
      <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
          <property>
            <name>loggerPath</name>
            <value>conf/log4j.properties</value>
          </property>
        </systemProperties>
        <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1500m</argLine>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <!-- attach test jar -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
            <goal>test-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>add_sources</id>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>add-source</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <sources>
              <source>src/main/java</source>
            </sources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>add_test_sources</id>
          <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <sources>
              <source>src/test/java</source>
            </sources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-annotations-version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- HTTP client: jersey-client -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- JSON processing: jackson -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>${jodatime-version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Base64 encoding that works in both JVM and Android -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.brsanthu</groupId>
    <artifactId>migbase64</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- test dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit-version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <swagger-annotations-version>1.5.8</swagger-annotations-version>
  <jersey-version>1.18</jersey-version>
  <jackson-version>2.4.2</jackson-version>
  <jodatime-version>2.3</jodatime-version>
  <maven-plugin-version>1.0.0</maven-plugin-version>
  <junit-version>4.8.1</junit-version>
</properties>
```

Manifest file: (jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Bnd-LastModified: 1407990182364
    Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_55
    Built-By: tatu
    Bundle-Description: General data-binding functionality for Jackson: work
     s on core streaming API
    Bundle-DocURL: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome
    Bundle-License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
    Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
    Bundle-Name: jackson-databind
    Bundle-SymbolicName: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind
    Bundle-Vendor: FasterXML
    Bundle-Version: 2.4.2
    Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
    Export-Package: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;version="2.4.2",com.faste
     rxml.jackson.databind.annotation;version="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.jackson.
     databind.cfg;version="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser;versi
     on="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl;version="2.4.2",co
     m.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std;version="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.ja
     ckson.databind.exc;version="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext;v
     ersion="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect;version="2.4.2
     ",com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonschema;version="2.4.2",com.fasterx
     ml.jackson.databind.jsonFormatVisitors;version="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.ja
     ckson.databind.jsontype;version="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.
     jsontype.impl;version="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module;ver
     sion="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node;version="2.4.2",com.fa
     sterxml.jackson.databind.ser;version="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.jackson.data
     bind.ser.impl;version="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std;ve
     rsion="2.4.2",com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type;version="2.4.2",com.f
     asterxml.jackson.databind.util;version="2.4.2"
    Implementation-Build-Date: 2014-08-13 21:22:55-0700
    Implementation-Title: jackson-databind
    Implementation-Vendor: FasterXML
    Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.fasterxml.jackson.core
    Implementation-Version: 2.4.2
    Import-Package: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;version="[2.4.0,2.5)",c
     om.fasterxml.jackson.core;version="[2.4.2,2.5)",com.fasterxml.jackson.c
     ore.base;version="[2.4.2,2.5)",com.fasterxml.jackson.core.format;versio
     n="[2.4.2,2.5)",com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io;version="[2.4.2,2.5)",com
     .fasterxml.jackson.core.json;version="[2.4.2,2.5)",com.fasterxml.jackso
     n.core.type;version="[2.4.2,2.5)",com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util;versi
     on="[2.4.2,2.5)",javax.xml.datatype,javax.xml.namespace,javax.xml.parse
     rs,org.w3c.dom,org.w3c.dom.bootstrap,org.w3c.dom.ls,org.xml.sax
    Specification-Title: jackson-databind
    Specification-Vendor: FasterXML
    Specification-Version: 2.4.2
    Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
    X-Compile-Source-JDK: 1.6
    X-Compile-Target-JDK: 1.6
```

Comment: class not found exception happens when in run time .class file is not found even it is found in compile time.for me,whenever class not found exception happen,I clean my project,and rebuild the project in eclipse ,and I go to check .class file is found again or not .

Comment: @sawyinwaimon What do I do here? I hope I am running the file from the correct directory? I compiled and am running it from `classes` directory inside `target` directory`

Comment: do u know in which directory classes folder exist?plz go to check classes folder.if you run project by using eclipse IDE,can you do like that what i said,"clean the project,rebuild,and run the project again".

Comment: @sawyinwaimon I am not using eclipse. Just the command line tools.

Comment: Add your Tester  class and describe how you are trying to run it

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the manifest file. [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Create a manifest file and add a classpath there:

```
Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

To automate the generation of the manifest classpath use the folowing maven plugin:

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <index>true</index>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Where do I keep this file?

Comment: In the META-INF folder. You could also use an IDE. The IDE will automaticaly create it for you.

Comment: Or you might use a maven plugin for the automation: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html

Comment: Edited and posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112495/discussion-between-tak3shi-and-karooka).

Answer (score -1):

try this->

1. right click on project
2. click on Build Path -> Configure Build Path
3. then in left panel find the Deployement Assembly and click on this
4. see on right side click on Add
5. click on Java Build Path Entries
6. after that double click on Maven Dependencies
7. click on Apply and Ok
8. redeploy your code.